# Many to many relation with Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-rest

I have a question regarding Many to Many relation and how is it handled by Hibernate.

I have to entities I need to be connected. I decided to use unidirectional Many to Many, so I defined it like:

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "x_y_RELATION",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "x_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns =
                    @JoinColumn(name = "y_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    )
    private Set<YEntity> yEntities;
```

To get the x entities I'm using  `@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "x-api", path = "x-api")` on interface extending `CrudRepository<X, Long>`.

My problem is that during `findAll()` method (which I specified as native query for irrelevant reasons, it's like `SELECT * FROM X`) query is executed as defined, but then come messages from Hibernate logger that it performs next selects to fetch the Y. My assumption was that with default fetch type = `LAZY` this data won't be instantly fetched. Am I missing something? Or this is just default behavior in such a case? Can I modify it? I know I can create second entity for X without this relation, but I'm trying to find other solution.

**EDIT**

To have better understanding of what's going on I added test endpoint to omit `@RepositoryRestResource` and it looks like everything on the db/hibernate level is ok. I was able to execute `findAll()` and return x entities without fetching anything from ys. Looks like `Spring Data Rest` enforces response to be fully loaded. Is there a way to configure it?

Comment: share with us your custom query for `findAll` and also the code that invokes it